# Chamar função depois de escolher data

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, datepicker

Bom dia,

Tenho um input text com um datepicker. 
O input tem uma função validator que altera a cor do input conforme o texto esteja certo ou errado.

Mas neste caso como não escrevo diretamente no input e apenas faço click no datepicker, a função validator não é chamada.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Temos de ver o código do teu datepicker. É um plugin ou é o nativo do HTML5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser isso que precise

```
$("#SeuInput").on("change", function(){
  alert("Mudou o valor");
  suafuncaoaqui();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que assim resolveria o seu caso:

```
 $( "#input" )
        .datepicker({
         //regras do datapicker aqui
 })
 .on( "change", function() {
     //this é o elemento input, o valor seria: this.value
     suaFuncaoDeValidacaoAqui(this);
  });
```

ou se preferir, pegar a data, na mesma função:

```
 .on( "change", function() {
     suaFuncaoDeValidacaoAqui(getDate(this));
  });

 function getDate( element ) {
          var date;
          try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
          } catch( error ) {
            date = null;
          }
      return date;
    }
```